# How to determine which table of a multitable view are updatable?

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

Update: My problem doesn't seem to be with the SQL server.  I executed an update statement inside the database manually against the view and I was able to update the Bar table.  I'll close this and research the OleDbDataAdapters more since I think the problem lies with them.

This question applies to MS SQL Server 2000.  **How do I determine which table of the multitable view can be modified?**

I have the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView
AS
SELECT     dbo.Foo.Id, dbo.Bar.Id, dbo.Foo.column1, dbo.Foo.column2,
           dbo.Foo.column3, dbo.Bar.column1, dbo.Bar.column2, 
           dbo.Bar.column3
FROM       dbo.Bar INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Foo ON dbo.Bar.Id = dbo.Foo.ForeignId
```

When I update this view, (using VB.NET OleDbDataAdapters), I can update columns of Foo, but not columns of Bar.  My investigation into this tells me that in a multitable view like this that MS SQL server only allows you to update one of the tables.  So my question is, how does SQL server determine which table can be updated?

I tried a test where I edit the fields of a particular row from the view.  Afterwards, I used the OleDbDataAdapter to update the view.  Only the edits to the Foo table were accepted.  The edits to the Bar table were ignored (no exception thrown).

***Is there a way to predict which of the tables can be updated or a way to control which one?***  What if I wanted Bar to be the updateable table instead of Foo?

Update:  I found this on google, MS SQL Server 2000 Unleased:

http://books.google.com/books?id=G2YqBS9CQ0AC&pg=RA1-PA713&lpg=RA1-PA713&dq=ms+sql+server+"multitable+view"++updated&source=bl&ots=ZuQXIlEPbO&sig=JbgdDe5yU73aSkxh-SLDdtMYZDs&hl=en&ei=b-0SSq-aHZOitgPB38zgDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1#PRA1-PA713,M1

(For some reason the URL I'm trying to paste doesn't work with this site, sorry that you have to copy&paste.)

Which says:

- An update through a multitable view ***cannot*** affect more than ***one*** underlying base table.
- A delete cannot be executed against multitable views.

But, I don't yet see an answer to my question.

Again, my question is:

***How do I determine which table of the multitable view can be modified?***

I realize I can write two update statements one for each table.  My concern is different.  I need to audit code that uses views like the one above and does updates on the views.  I was hoping to find a way to determine which parts of the updates will be silently ignored.

Example:

I edit Bar.Column1 and then call the Update() method of the OleDbDataAdapter.  This results in the Bar table not being modified nor is an exception thrown.  If I edit Foo.Column2 then call Update() the Foo table does get modified.

Comment: When you are attempting to update Bar, are you simultaneously updating Foo?

Comment: Because I use the the OleDbDataAdapter I'm not sure of the exact SQL syntax that is fed to the database.  The data adapter pulls data directly from the view, so I had assumed it updates the view and not the individual tables.  Do you know how I can check this?

Comment: I should add, that I understand that updating the view causes the base tables to be updated.  I realize the view itself does not hold any data.  Sorry if that was confusing in what I wrote!

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but you always need to know the exact SQL your application is trying to execute to be able to troubleshoot an issue like this. You can run Profiler to get the code that is sent to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can update any table in the view, but only fields that are all in the same table in that statement. If you need to update fields from two tables in a view, then you must write two update statements.

Personally I prefer not to update or delete from views at all. I use the base tables for that.

There are also rules concerning whether view is updateble. See Books online. Search for this:
views-SQL Server, modifying data

Comment: If I understand you, you are telling me to update each base table instead of updating the view.  As far as I can tell, that defeats the purpose of the view, eg., the client code must know the structure of the base tables.

Comment: And, more to the point.  I realize I can update the tables independently of the view.  Instead, I wanted to find out how MS SQL Server determines which of the two tables I can update.  The behavior I'm seeing is that changes to Bar are ignored but changes to Foo are saved.

Comment: If you just make a change to a field in Bar and not any fields in Foo would they save? SQL Server doen't pick just one table it will update. The update can only involve one table even if you update the view. Yes the client code must know the structure of the base tables in any event because you cannot update fields from two tables at the same time, ever.

Answer (score -1):

You need to be able to uniquely identify the row in the table by returning the primary key. Try returning `dbo.Bar.Id` in the view, and you should be able to edit columns in table `Bar`.

Comment: In my actual view I do include Bar.Id in the select.  I'll update the question to match.  Any other ideas?